# raise RuntimeError(message) from e RuntimeError: Error compiling objects for extension

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to run the git program "**Deep Hough Transform for Semantic Line Detection**" from past two week and also I changed so many NVIDIA version and pytorch version and many more thing. when Install all dependencies and try to run **python setup.py build** form that stage I am unable to run my program but still have error is any one please help me as soon as possible. I will be thank full to you.

**Project link** :
https://github.com/Hanqer/deep-hough-transform

**Error Message:**
your text
File "C:\Users\Qunut\Desktop\D_conveyor_detact\Qenv\lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 345, in run
self.build_extensions()
File "C:\Users\Qunut\Desktop\D_conveyor_detact\Qenv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 873, in build_extensions
build_ext.build_extensions(self)
File "C:\Users\Qunut\Desktop\D_conveyor_detact\Qenv\lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 467, in build_extensions
self._build_extensions_serial()
File "C:\Users\Qunut\Desktop\D_conveyor_detact\Qenv\lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 493, in _build_extensions_serial
self.build_extension(ext)
File "C:\Users\Qunut\Desktop\D_conveyor_detact\Qenv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 249, in build_extension
_build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
File "C:\Users\Qunut\Desktop\D_conveyor_detact\Qenv\lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 548, in build_extension
objects = self.compiler.compile(
File "C:\Users\Qunut\Desktop\D_conveyor_detact\Qenv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 845, in win_wrap_ninja_compile
_write_ninja_file_and_compile_objects(
File "C:\Users\Qunut\Desktop\D_conveyor_detact\Qenv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1774, in _write_ninja_file_and_compile_objects
_run_ninja_build(
File "C:\Users\Qunut\Desktop\D_conveyor_detact\Qenv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 2116, in _run_ninja_build
raise RuntimeError(message) from e
RuntimeError: Error compiling objects for extension

[Error message is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7wUu.jpg)

**Package list is given in below**.

Package            Version

---

certifi            2023.7.22
charset-normalizer 3.3.2
colorama           0.4.6
contourpy          1.2.0
cycler             0.12.1
filelock           3.13.1
fonttools          4.44.0
fsspec             2023.10.0
idna               3.4
imageio            2.32.0
Jinja2             3.1.2
kiwisolver         1.4.5
lazy_loader        0.3
MarkupSafe         2.1.3
matplotlib         3.8.1
mpmath             1.3.0
networkx           3.2.1
ninja              1.11.1.1
numpy              1.26.1
opencv-python      4.8.1.78
packaging          23.2
Pillow             10.0.1
pip                23.3.1
POT                0.9.1
pyparsing          3.1.1
python-dateutil    2.8.2
requests           2.31.0
scikit-image       0.22.0
scipy              1.11.3
setuptools         68.2.2
six                1.16.0
sympy              1.12
tifffile           2023.9.26
torch              2.1.0+cu121
torchaudio         2.1.0+cu121
torchvision        0.16.0
tqdm               4.66.1
typing_extensions  4.8.0
urllib3            2.0.7
wheel              0.41.2
yml                0.0.1

I tried visual studio 2015, 2019 and now using 2022
NVIDIA 10, 9,and many other and now I am using CUDA 12.1

I already attach all details and want help to run setup.py build to install Deep-Hough.